# Eclipse plugin: Show window with scrollable text

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

In an eclipse plugin, I try to show the user a dialog that just contains a long text. This text should be scrollable.

I tried:

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
 {
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    Text text = new Text(container, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.MULTI);

    text.setText("   " + command + "\n\r\n\r" + result);

    return container;
 }
```

The text is then shown with a disabled scrollbar (although it is larger than the size of the window). How do I enable scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be, that your layoutdata on the text is not limited. So SWT appears to have no idea when to enable scrolling.

Setting griddata to fill both did not work for me with your code (just tried).

However, this will:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell s = new Shell(display);

    s.setSize(300, 300);
    s.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

    Composite c = new Composite(s, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    Text text = new Text(c, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, false, false);
    gridData.heightHint = 200;
    gridData.widthHint = 200;
    text.setLayoutData(gridData);

    text.setBackground(s.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

    text.setSize(250, 250);

    Font stdFont = new Font(text.getDisplay(), new FontData("Consolas", 11, SWT.NORMAL));

    text.setFont(stdFont);

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    for (int row = 0; row < 40; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            buffer.append("Word ");
        }
        buffer.append("\n");
    }

    text.setText(buffer.toString());

    s.open();



    while (!s.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();

}
```

By restricting the size of your Text properly (with layoutdata, not setting the size), SWT now knows when the text is bigger than the area and enables scrolling.

Mind you, your solution does work, if you type something after creating (i know not possible for your case).

Answer (score 0):

I works if you also set

```
text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
```